# Unhandled exception at 0x78F90870 (ucrtbased.dll) in Metrics_Alpha.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, excel, windows, visual-c++

Trying to work with Excel files using C++ (as a pretty "less-than-professional" programmer). It seems I brought all the libraries in correctly, etc; if I need to post those and included SDKs, I can. However, I'm running into the above error.

Here is where I am working with the Excel file directly:

```
void themSheets() {
    cout << endl << endl;
    try {
        Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXL;
        pXL->Workbooks->Open(L"C:/Users/Person/source/repos/Metrics_Alpha/Metrics_Alpha/poooopy.xlsx");
        pXL->PutVisible(0, FALSE);

        Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = pXL->ActiveSheet;
        pSheet->Name = L"Sheet1";
        Excel::RangePtr pRange = pSheet->Cells;

        pRange->Item[1][1] = 5.21;
        double apples = pRange->Item[1][1];
        cout << endl << apples;
        pXL->Workbooks->Close();
    }
    catch (_com_error & error) {
        cout << error.Description() << endl;
    }
}
```

And here is where the exception happens:

```
    _NODISCARD static _CONSTEXPR17 size_t length(_In_z_ const _Elem* const _First) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
    // find length of null-terminated string
#if _HAS_CXX17
#ifdef __cpp_char8_t
        if constexpr (is_same_v<_Elem, char8_t>) {
#if _HAS_U8_INTRINSICS
            return __builtin_u8strlen(_First);
#else // ^^^ use u8 intrinsics / no u8 intrinsics vvv
            return _Primary_char_traits::length(_First);
#endif // _HAS_U8_INTRINSICS
        } else
#endif // __cpp_char8_t
        {
            return __builtin_strlen(_First);
        }
#else // _HAS_CXX17
        return _CSTD strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_First)); **<--Happens right here**
#endif // _HAS_CXX17
    }
```

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer. Your debugger will show you where.

Comment: I annotated where the debugger shows me the null pointer, I just don't know how to fix that pointer. I assume it's because of the file I am calling and not inherently an incorrect thing from the dll

Comment: The exact location where the access violation is observed isn't nearly as helpful as the sequence of operations that led to it. That information is captured in the debugger's [Call Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window) window (assuming you are using Visual Studio's debugger). Moving down in the call stack will eventually trace back to user-authored code responsible for the access violation.

Comment: @IInspectable
My call stack references the location I posted.
 ucrtbased.dll!strlen(unsigned char * buf) Line 81 Unknown


> Metrics_Alpha.exe!std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::length(const char * const _First) Line 389 C++

  Metrics_Alpha.exe!std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & _Ostr, const char * _Val) Line` `739 C++

Comment: You have posted code from your C++ Standard Library implementation. That's where the access violation happens. Not due to a bug in your C++ Standard Library implementation, but in **your** code that calls into it, feeding it incorrect values. You need to move to stack frames lower in the call stack until you reach your code. You're probably going to wind up at `cout << error.Description()`, where you're feeding a null pointer into the output operator. That's a guess. If you want a definitive answer, post the call stack.

Comment: Sorry, new to posting on StackOverflow but you're right, I did arrive at `cout << error.Description()`. Also, sorry the formatting on that was terrible, I tried to fix it for as long as I could. But now my error is at `pXL->Workbooks->Open(...);`. It gives a _com_error, but in all examples I can find of working with excel in this way, it is implemented like this. Thanks for your help so far btw.

Comment: `pXL` is a null pointer. You need to call `pXL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application")` (to run a new Excel instance) or `GetActiveObject` (if you believe an Excel instance is already running, and you want to attach to it).

Comment: @igo I'm not convinced that `pXL` is a null pointer. If it were, then dereferencing it wouldn't wind up in a C++ exception handler, and it's highly unlikely that indexing into a vtable results in an in address of 0. It's much more reasonable to assume that `Description()` returns a null pointer, and `operator<<` calls `strlen` on that null pointer, which coincides with the observations. If you want to get better error information, replace `Description()` with [`Error()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-error). That'll output the numeric error value.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, `_ApplicationPtr` is a smart pointer, a typedef for `_com_ptr_t`. I imagine its `operator->` checks for the wrapped raw pointer being null, and throws `_com_error`. This is the root cause of the problem. It's possible that `cout << error.Description()` is also wrong, and turns this C++ exception into a hard crash. `Description()` uses rich error information (from `IErroInfo`), which wouldn't be set in this case; though it's a bit surprising that `_bstr_t::operator char*` would return null, and not a pointer to an empty string, for an empty `_bstr_t`.

Comment: @igo That's just following the `BSTR` protocol, where `""` and `nullptr` have identical semantics. That may be unusual and surprising, but when `_bstr_t` is constructed from a `nullptr` (which is a perfectly legal representation of an empty `BSTR`) then `operator char*` will return a `nullptr` as well. Though you are probably correct that dereferencing the unseated `pXL` smart pointer is throwing a `_com_error`.

Comment: Please don't put "[SOLVED]" in the title. Instead, post an answer and accept that. That's how future visitors discover questions that have answers. I'm rolling back your edit for now. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details.

Comment: Yeah, last time I tried that it didn't actually post it so I tried that way. When I get home today I will post the full answer because it's a little more in depth about what you guys were talking about and it'd because of a really silly error I made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The major issue was I was missing this block of code in my main:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hr << endl;
        return hr;
    }

    Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXL;

    if (FAILED(pXL.CreateInstance("Excel.Application")))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize Excel::_Application!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```